# No Light Groups under Passes with View Layer

Tags: lighting

[image]

I am using 3.6, but as you can see, there is no Light Group option for some reason.

Is it something that requires extra setup to show?

Comment: What version is this? Is it the official 3.6.0 or some nightly build? In my 3.6.0 there is no *Effects* section.

Comment: it is the official 3.6.0. I just downloaded it from the blender.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Light Groups* are available in Cycles, not Eevee

Comment: thank you for the answer!